# Latex math template

Tags: templates

Does anyone know how to get or code this template and can u suggest some like this

[image]

Comment: Have a look here: https://de.overleaf.com/gallery/tagged/math/page/2 . The Assignment seems to be close. // The spiral drawings can be done e.g. by Tikz. Have a look into the short and huge manual at: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf .

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.